# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes on shutdown/restart on Dell XPS 15' 9560 & won't boot after hard shutdown

Tags: boot, nvidia, dell, shutdown

I use a Dell XPS 15' 9560. It has 16GB RAM, i7 processor, Nvidia GTX1050 graphic card, 512 SSD. I ran Windows10 home until now. 
I've finally tweaked some settings in BIOS config and installed Ubuntu.
But, when I click restart to complete installation, it freezes my computer. I then have to do a force shutdown. Still, when I boot the computer it freezes on boot as well. 
I'm currently running ubuntu from a bootable pen drive. I've tried a new config and I'm reinstalling ubuntu alongside right now. 
Need help please.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely needs the `nouveau.modeset=0` fix...

ie: add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"` to `/etc/default/grub` file.

But you can only do that if you can boot..

So, you would need to press `e` when you see the grub load screen.
and then manually edit the grub settings

so that the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line looks like this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"`

assuming that allows you to boot, add the setting permanently
by running:
`sudo gedit /etc/default/grup`
and making the change there.

also [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)